# Certain operations like 'ls' hang in 4-node gluster setup

Tags: glusterfs

I have a 4-node gluster setup with replication set to 2. The 'ls' command hangs on the Gluster mount that I have created. The other operations such as creating a file or reading a file work fine.

However, ls, works perfectly fine when I setup only 2 nodes on it. I have tried this on Gluster version 3.3.1 as well as version 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause of a change in ext4 file system.  Read this!  I been searching for hours to finally find this answer!  http://joejulian.name/blog/glusterfs-bit-by-ext4-structure-change/